# How to completely disable StreetPass?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, streetpass

I like StreetPass, but all the fake Mii's and cheaters (some people now build contraptions made of Knex that fake walking movement to get more playing coins, stuff like that...) pretty much force me to stop using it. :'(

I have removed all software from StreetPass Management (or whatever it's called in English) in System Settings, but it still says "StreetPass" in the HOME-menu. Now how do I completely disable it so it says "Local" again?

This must be possible since when I just had my Nintendo 3DS XL, it said "Local", until I first started up StreetPass Mii-Park.

Comment: Why does people getting coins force you to stop using StreetPass? I mean, what's the difference if they actually walked, instead of using Knex to fake it? It doesn't actually affect you, does it?

Comment: @nolonar the only thing I can think of is games like the warrior mii Plaza game, where you can use coins to gain a lot of warriors at once, but you can also choose not to fight armies that are much bigger than you (in fact, if the army is much bigger than you, the game actually encourages you not to fight)

Comment: what is knex in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

If you have disabled Streetpass for everything on that menu, you shouldn't pick up people in those games. The Streetpass on the home screen just says you have the ability to pick it up, not necessarily that it is active, if you don't have any games or the like you have allowed to use Streetpass.

You can turn off the network stuff with the switch on the side, but if I remember correctly, that also will mean you cannot connect to the Internet, so that is something to keep in mind.

I am not sure if you can turn off the Streetpass stuff for the mii Plaza, but you can just ignore it and not use it, if it isn't something you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple approaches to disabling the *StreetPass* function from your 3DS. Here are a few. **Note: there is no way to bring the "local" image on the top screen unless you are playing with someone else nearby with games such as Mario Kart 7 or Animal Crossing New Leaf.**

### Turning off the Wireless Communications

According to [Nintendo Support](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/3ds/en_la/ht_system.jsp):

**Push the wireless switch on the right side of the Nintendo 3DS down.
Verify that the wireless LED is off.**

### Disabling StreetPass via StreetPass Mii Plaza

You will have to enter the **StreetPass Mii Plaza** application on the Home Menu. When you have access to move around, go to Settings, which should be a **Red Toolbox with a wrench sticking out of it.** When you press it, the first option will say StreetPass. The next screen will ask, "Activate StreetPass?" under it, it states "*selecting no will deactivate StreetPass*." All you have to do is press *No* and StreetPass should be deactivated.

### Deactivating Titles using StreetPass Functions

As you have mentioned, this is another great method to stop getting StreetPass tags for the games that utilize StreetPass-related functions. Unfortunately, this will not prevent the StreetPass tags from arriving at the StreetPass Mii Plaza. You are required to proceed with the previous approach to completely disable the StreetPass function.

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you leave your house, you can switch off Streetpass by turning off all wireless communications with the side switch. Most games will ask you to activate Streetpass manually once you start them, just don't do so. Finally, you can also delete your Mii so you won't have anyone on your Streetpass plaza.

Comment: Delete my Mii!?

Comment: I am not sure why they need to delete their Mii, that doesn't change the StreetPass abilities of anything.

Comment: If he doesn't have a Mii he can't have a Streetpass Plaza = no streetpasses.